# Is there a way to save a dataframes from an R package as an hdf5 to load into python?

Tags: python, r, hdf5

I'm trying to export each dataset from the CASdatasets package (http://cas.uqam.ca/) loop through each and save them to an `hdf5` file for each to load into python as pandas dataframes.  However, I'm not as familiar with R as python.  Is there a way to loop through each dataset in the package and save each to a disk as an `hdf5` file?

so far, I have

```
install.packages("CASdatasets", repos = "http://dutangc.free.fr/pub/RRepos/", type="source")
library(CASdatasets)
```

Comment: Youmight find this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/feather/versions/0.3.5 as an interesting alternative.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/rhdf5/inst/doc/rhdf5.html

Comment: also refer [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdf5r/index.html)

Comment: thanks to all.  is there some efficient r loop that will pull each dataset out of the CASdatasets package to then save or transform using feather or rpy2?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do so. This one here loads the rda files directly from the library into a fresh environment. From there, you can export to any file format.

```
library(feather)

all_data <- list.files(
  file.path(.libPaths()[1], "CASdatasets", "data"), 
  pattern = "\\.rda", 
  full.names = TRUE
)

# Load all files into a fresh environment
data_env <- new.env()
lapply(all_data, load, envir = data_env)

# Export into your favourite format
for (f in names(data_env)[1:3]) {
  if (is.data.frame(f))
    write_feather(data_env[[f]], paste(f, ".feather"))
  else
    warning(f)
}
```